# How to place figures between paragraphs?

Tags: floats, paragraphs

I want to insert figures between text just like this:

[image].

So I use the following code:

```
**
\begin{document}
Text here.
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[!h]{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{graph01.png}
        \caption{A tree.}
    \end{subfigure}
~
    \begin{subfigure}[!h]{0.3\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{graph02.png}
        \caption{Petersen's graph}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Examples of a graph}
\end{figure}
Text here again.
\end{document}
```

**

The image was not exact in the position where I want it to be. Instead, the image is placed on another page. How can I change that?

Comment: welcome to tex.se! just add option `[htb]` to `figure` environment, like `\begin{figure}[htb]` . if between paragraphs will be enough place, figures will appear there.

Comment: An in depth discussion on how floats are placed can be found here: [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/134144)

Comment: note the _only_ reason to use a `figure` enviornment is to allow it to be moved in that way. If you use `\includegraphics` directly it is not moved.

Comment: Supplement to @DavidCarlisle’s comment: for best results, you can include the `\includegraphics` command in a `center` environment.  If, in addition, you want to caption the figure, you can do so by means of the `caption` package and its `\captionof` command.  An alternative solution is to load the `float` package and use the `H` (capital) placement specifier.

Comment: subfigure doesn't use positioning at all, so the [!h} is at best useless.  [htp] for the figure means here if possible, top of the next page if not, or in a page of nothing but floats.  I have yet to find a case where adding ! did anything useful.